# Converting an opengl screen to bytes and back to Texture in unity

Tags: opengl, unity-game-engine, textures

I have a opengl software which genertes a window and then sends its bytes through a socket to unity. 
The opengl software retrieves the data:

```
glreadPixels(0,0,width,height,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
```

where 'buffer' is byte[] buffer which is being sent to the unity app. There I try to convert it back to an image by doing:

```
Texture2D t = new Texture(width,hight,Textureformat.ETC2_RGB,false);
t.LoadRawTextureData(buffer);
t.Applay();
```

However the texture apears as black screen with colorful stains which are moving and disapearing cyclically.
I chose the 'ETC2_RGB' format because it looked relevant, but I also tried some more formats from [TextureFormat](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextureFormat.html), and all of them looked white\black with colorful dots\pink, etc. What are the right convertions that I should choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong texture format. `ETC2_RGB` is a compressed format with 4 bits per pixel. What you query from `glReadPixel` is a uncompressed format with 8 bits per channel. The format for this is `Textureformat.RGB24`.

Comment: With this format it apears like static diagonal Lines from colorful dots and a thick colorful line on the side, while my opengl screen is text writen in green with linear green frame.